# Lemma 39.2 Munkres

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a metrizable space and let $A$ be an open covering of $X$.

Let us use the well-ordering theorem and choose a well-ordering $\le$ for $A$.

Choose a metric for $X$ and fix a positive integer $n$. Given an element $U$ of $A$, let

 \begin{align} S_{n}(U)=\{x |B(x,1/n)\subset U\} \end{align}

How then is $S_{n}(U)$ closed?

I found this written on Page 246 of *Topology*, Second Edition, Munkres.

Thanks!

[image: extract from the mentioned book, so it is clearer the context]

Comment: Does the well-ordering of $A$ ever come into play?

Comment: Well, I don't really know, there is no proof in the book for this. (He just added the fact the set is closed parenthetically).

Comment: $B(x,1/n)$ is a subset of $X$? How can it be a subset of a covering of $X$?

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini Well, $S_n(U)$ is only defined for $U ∈ A$. Or is it $U ⊂ A$ and in the definition of $S_n (U)$ it should read $B(x,1/n) ∈ U$? You should clarify this, Raghav.

Comment: Yes, I've edited it, $U$ is an element of the collection, so it's an open set. That was a mistake, I wrote $U$ as though it belonged to $A$ (which is just a collection).

Comment: But now $U$ is any open set... $A$ does not come into play.

Comment: No, $U$ is an open set belonging to the collection $A$ and $A$ is an open covering of $X$.

Comment: @Raghav: that means that $U$ is any open set. Please try to copy the statement as is on the book...

Comment: The question as it is written right now, is copied verbatim from the textbook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try to show that $X \setminus  S_n(U)$ is open (note that $n$ is fixed from now on): let $p$ be a point such that $p \notin S_n(U)$, so $B(p, \frac{1}{n})$ is not a subset of $U$. This means that for some $q$ with $d(p,q) < \frac{1}{n}$, we have that $q \notin U$. So $q$ witnesses that $p$ is outside $S_n(U)$. The idea is that a small enough open ball around $p$ will still have the same witness $q$: let $r = \frac{1}{n} - d(p,q) > 0$.

For any $x$, if $d(p,x) < r$, then $d(x,q) \le d(x,p) + d(p,q) < r + d(p,q) = \frac{1}{n}$. So indeed, $q$ still shows that $B(x, \frac{1}{n})$ is not a subset of $U$, so $x \in B(p,r)$ implies $x \notin S_n(U)$, or $B(p,r) \subset X \setminus S_n(U)$. So the complement of $S_n(U)$ is open, so $S_n(U)$ is closed.